# How to use ICollection property to do a bool check

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following entities:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}

public class LineItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to just check if an order has large items (qty > 50), so I would like to add a property to Order class like so:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }

    public bool HasLargeItems
    {
        get
        {
            return LineItems.Any(l => l.Qty > 50);
        }
    }
}
```

This however, doesn't work because of lazy-loading. But if I use .Include(o => o.LineItems), it will fetch all the LineItems and then do an in-memory comparison. I would rather have this generate and execute a query against the db and just get me back a boolean value.

Is this possible to do as a property of Order entity, or do I have to write some other external query object which uses DbContext to perform these kinds of checks?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using anonymous select

```
   var order = dbContext.Orders
     .Where(o => o.Id == id)
     .Select(o => new { Order = o, HasLargeItems = o.LineItems.Count > 50 })
     .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I know how I can do this outside of the class. I am just asking if it's possible to do efficiently as a property of the entity without having access to dbContext.

Comment: Maybe not then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help:

```
public bool HasItems
    {
        get{return LineItems.AsQueryable().Any(x => false);}
    }
```